# When to use weight decay for ADAM optimiser?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, gradient-descent, adam

If you use weight decay for gradient descent (ADAM specifically) do you need to use regularisation for loss function?

I believe the answer is yes since the gradient descent involves the differentiation of the loss function and hence the weight decay part of the loss function.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Robert, if you found this answer helpful, then please consider upvoting and/or accepting it

Answer (score 4):

Weight decay is a form of regularization that changes the objective function. You can also use other regularization techniques if you’d like.

Either way, weight decay does alter the values used to update each parameter, because the gradient is computed for a different function: the one that includes weight decay.